# Inequality regarding unitary invariance of the Frobenius norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$, with SVDs $A = U_A \Sigma_A V_A^T$ and $B = U_B \Sigma_B V_B^T$. I want to show that
$$
  || \Sigma_A - \Sigma_B ||_F \leq || A - U B V^T ||_F
$$ 
where $U, V$ are arbitrary unitary matrices of appropriate dimension (this exercise comes from http://math.ecnu.edu.cn/~jypan/Teaching/books/SVD.pdf, 17.5, problem 5).

I know that by unitary invariance of the Frobenius norm we have $ || B ||_F = || U B V ||_F$ for any appropriately sized $U, V$. Thus, I can show that
$$
  || \Sigma_A - \Sigma_B ||_F = || A - U_A U_B^T B V_B V_A^T ||_F
$$

How do I relate this to $U$,$V$?

Comment: Maybe the transpose $\cdot^T$ should be conjugate transpose $\cdot^*$?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually. The result follows given the trace inequality:

$$
  | \mathrm{Tr}(A B^T)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sigma_i(A) \sigma_i(B)
$$